# Fire xaml page in new web browser

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

Greeting,
I have 2 xaml pages in my silver light  application.

First page has a button.

I want when I click this button to fire the second xaml page in new web browser.

please advice how to do this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Here's the msdn example 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743613.aspx